# Proving or disproving continuity of integral operator on $(C^0([0, 1])$ in $ |\cdot|_\infty$ Norm

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, metric-spaces

$\text{Consider } (C^0([0, 1]), |\cdot|_\infty). \text{ Then, } T: C^0([0, 1]) \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \text{ with } T(f) = \int_0^1 f(x)^2 , dx \text{ is continuous.}$

I guess that it's not correct and my counter example is the following:

Consider the sequence of functions $f_n(x) = nx^n$ defined on the interval $[0, 1]$. Let $f(x) = 0$ be the zero function.

We can see that $f_n(x)$ converges pointwise to $f(x)$ as $n$ tends to infinity. However, when we compute the integral $\int_0^1 f_n(x)^2 \, dx$, we get:

$
\int_0^1 (nx^n)^2 \, dx = \int_0^1 n^2x^{2n} \, dx = \frac{n^2}{2n+1}
$

As $n$ tends to infinity, $\frac{n^2}{2n+1}$ does not converge to zero. Therefore, the operator $T(f) = \int_0^1 f(x)^2 \, dx$ is not continuous on the space $C^0([0, 1])$ with the sup norm.

Is that a good counter example?

Comment: The limit function $f$ is not integrable in [0,1], as $\lim_n f_n(1) = \lim_n n = \infty$.

Comment: could u help me to create a counter example? I'm pretty much struggling with that

Comment: I have posted a full proof

Comment: Note: OP's error is in trying to construct a counter example using pointwise limits. One of the first "lessons" when doing metric function spaces is that the convergence in $||_\infty$ implies pointwise convergence, but generally not the other way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is indeed correct, we can do a standard $\epsilon - \delta$ proof. Let $\epsilon > 0$, $\delta > 0$ and $f, g \in C^0[0,1]$ such that $|f - g|_\infty < \delta$. Then we have that:
$$|T(g) - T(f)|_\infty = \left| \int^1_0 f^2(x) - g^2(x) dx \right| \leq \int^1_0 |f(x) - g(x)| |f(x) + g(x)| dx$$

Note that $|f(x) - g(x)| \leq \delta$ and $|f(x) + g(x)| < 2 \max(f, g)$ so:
$$
|T(g) - T(f)|_\infty < 2 \delta \max(f, g)
$$
and we can choose $\delta < \frac{1}{2} \max(f, g)$.

Another way to prove it is by noting that both the function $f \mapsto f^2$ and the standard integral operator $f \to \int^1_0 f$ are continuous, and your operator is just the composition of both.